# Failed to install rbenv on macOS Monterey 12.3.1 Intel core i5

Tags: rbenv

I have tried to install with normal installation (rbenv install 2.7.6) or with RUBY_CFLAGS still no luck!

```
rbenv --version
rbenv 1.2.0
```

,

```
gem which cocoapods
/Users/mymac/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods.rb
```

,

```
Xcode 13.4
```

,

```
mymac@MacBook-Pro% RUBY_CFLAGS="-Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration" rbenv install 2.7.6
    Downloading ruby-2.7.6.tar.bz2...
    -> https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.7/ruby-2.7.6.tar.bz2
    Installing ruby-2.7.6...
    ruby-build: using readline from homebrew
    
    BUILD FAILED (macOS 12.3.1 using ruby-build 20220426)
    
    Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/n5/d88l_sl9071gns5xdqk_myww0000gn/T/ruby-build.20220528201149.40536.2UiW6F
    Results logged to /var/folders/n5/d88l_sl9071gns5xdqk_myww0000gn/T/ruby-build.20220528201149.40536.log
    
    Last 10 log lines:
        from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:846:in `block (2 levels) in install_default_gem'
        from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:279:in `open_for_install'
        from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:845:in `block in install_default_gem'
        from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:835:in `each'
        from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:835:in `install_default_gem'
        from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:799:in `block in <main>'
        from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:950:in `block in <main>'
        from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:947:in `each'
        from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:947:in `<main>'
    make: *** [do-install-all] Error 1
```

Please anybody help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The error saying you are trying to downgrade the env.

check

```
ruby -v
```

upgrade it to latest version

```
rbenv install 3.1.2 # or whichever is latest
```

See this https://gorails.com/setup/osx/12-monterey

follow it with

```
rbenv global 3.1.2
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
gem update --system
```